# How do I parameterize this raw ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have a legacy code that has everything raw types and I am trying to remove raw types. I have this one ArrayList object that holds String arrays, String objects, Integer objects all into it.

```
List arLst = new ArrayList();
arlst.add(strngArr) //String Array
arrlst.add(intObj)  //Integer Object
arrlst.add(heyItsString) //String Object
```

How would I parameterize it? Specifically, the addition of the String Array is causing issues for me in specifying any generic type for the Array List. Will appreciate suggestions.

Comment: I'm happy to see that you typed it as the interface and not the implementation class. It's not something you see often around here :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case, your only choice is to make it an `ArrayList<Object>` (so you can add elements of any reference type).

Answer (score 0):

Common smallest superclass of those three classes is Object. So you can do that or just leave it raw since (iirc) raw types take Objects anyway.